# Camel - Split() and doCatch(....) does not work

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to build a route that tries to validate an xml and if everything is correct then has to split this file otherwise an exception is thrown and it has to do something else. So I did the following:

```
from("file:"+fileOutboxTransformed+"?preMove=inprogress&move="+backupFolderTransformed+"/"+labelMessageType+"_${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}-${file:name.noext}.${file:ext}")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Got transformed file and sending it to jms queue: "+queue)
    .doTry()
        .to("validator:classpath:"+validator)
        .split(xPathMessageTypeSplit)
        .to("jms:"+queue+"?jmsMessageType=Text")
    .doCatch(ValidationException.class)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Validation Exception for message ${body}")
        .to("xslt:classpath:"+transformationsErrorAfter)
        .split(xPathNotificationSplit)
        .to("file:"+fileOutboxInvalid+"?fileName=${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.err2")
    .end();
```

But it does not compile (if I do not use the split then it compiles and works) and the error is:

```
The method doCatch(Class<ValidationException>) is undefined for the type ExpressionNode
```

So I tried the following

```
from("file:"+fileOutboxTransformed+"?preMove=inprogress&move="+backupFolderTransformed+"/"+labelMessageType+"_${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}-${file:name.noext}.${file:ext}")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Got transformed file and sending it to jms queue: "+queue)
    .doTry()
        .to("direct:validate")
    .doCatch(ValidationException.class)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Validation Exception for message ${body}")
        .to("xslt:classpath:"+transformationsErrorAfter)
        .split(xPathNotificationSplit)
        .to("file:"+fileOutboxInvalid+"?fileName=${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.err2")
    .end();

    from("direct:validate")
        .to("validator:classpath:"+validator)
        .to("direct:split_message");

    from("direct:split_message")
        .split(xPathMessageTypeSplit)
        .to("jms:"+queue+"?jmsMessageType=Text");
```

This time I get the error of duplicate endpoint

```
 org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route312 because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: Endpoint[direct://validate]
```

do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you put `.end()` just before the `.doCatch`?

Answer (score 7):

In order to get back to the doTry() block from a split() block (or choice or other nested type), you need to use the endDoTry(). Contrary to its name, this method will end the nested split block and return back to the doTry() DSL.

I'd use the first route you posted with these changes:

```
from("file:"+fileOutboxTransformed+"?preMove=inprogress&move="+backupFolderTransformed+"/"+labelMessageType+"_${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}-${file:name.noext}.${file:ext}")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Got transformed file and sending it to jms queue: "+queue)
    .doTry()
        .to("validator:classpath:"+validator)
        .split(xPathMessageTypeSplit)
            .to("jms:"+queue+"?jmsMessageType=Text")
        .endDoTry()
    .doCatch(ValidationException.class)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Validation Exception for message ${body}")
        .to("xslt:classpath:"+transformationsErrorAfter)
        .split(xPathNotificationSplit)
            .to("file:"+fileOutboxInvalid+"?fileName=${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.err2")
        .endDoTry()
    .end();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second try seems fine. The error you're getting is caused by two routes beginning with `from("direct:validate")`
Don't you have an other route in your application consuming from the same endpoint?

Edit : Try to name it differently, maybe validate exists already (in your app or inside camel)

Comment: no.. from("direct:validate") is the only one I have in the route

Comment: Maybe try to name it differently, just to see